# how to make a row using col-md-4 class where i can put images of exactly same dimensions?

Tags: html, css

i have to make two rows in my webpage to show 4 images per row. but when I put the images into the code, they show in different dimensions even when i have resized them for same dimensions. please help. the code for the row is given below:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
                   <div class="container">
                    <img src="images/resized/photo.jpg" 
                       alt="Avatar">
                        <div class="overlay">
                       <div class="text">Romance</div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the classes that cover the row are below:

```
    .container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.`container` is a class used by bootstrap and the way you called it in your css, messes up with the entire bootstrap grid system.

Rename the container class to something else like mycontainer should do the trick